# Javascript/AJAX works fine in everything but IE

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, internet-explorer-9

I have a simple program, and it works 100% in Firefox and Chrome, but it doesn't work in Internet Explorer (version 9).

A popup window is called from a page that lists all the scheduled appointments for the day. This is the code to that popup window:

```
<?php

$name = $_GET['name'];
#$type = $_GET['type'];
$type = "Regular";
$id   = $_GET['id'];

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $name; ?></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                font-family: Georgia;
            }
            .col1 {
                float: left;
                padding-right: .75em;
            }
            .col1 div { height: 1.5em; }
            .col2 div { height: 1.5em; }
            .col2 {
                float: left;
                padding-right: .5em;
            }
            .notes {
                clear: both;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function saveClose() {
                var xmlhttp;
                var getstring  = "";
                var d          = document;

                var start_hour = d.getElementsByName('start_hour')[0].value;
                var start_min  = d.getElementsByName('start_min')[0].value;
                var start_am   = d.getElementsByName('start_am')[0].value;

                var end_hour   = d.getElementsByName('end_hour')[0].value;
                var end_min    = d.getElementsByName('end_min')[0].value;
                var end_am     = d.getElementsByName('end_am')[0].value;

                var no_show    = d.getElementsByName('no_show')[0].checked;

                var notes      = d.getElementsByName('notes')[0].value;

                getstring += "?type=<?php echo $type ?>";
                getstring += "&id=<?php echo $id ?>";
                getstring += "&s_hour="+start_hour;
                getstring += "&s_min=" +start_min;
                getstring += "&s_am="  +start_am;
                getstring += "&e_hour="+end_hour;
                getstring += "&e_min=" +end_min;
                getstring += "&e_am="  +end_am;
                getstring += "&ns="    +no_show;
                getstring += "&notes=" +notes;

                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari;
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    // code for IE6, IE5;
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
                {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                    {
                        var reply = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        if (reply == "Successful!") {
                            setTimeout('self.close()', 1000);
                        } else {
                            document.getElementById('resultsContent').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        }
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById('resultsContent').innerHTML = "Saving...";
                    }
                }

                xmlhttp.open("GET", "saveClose.php"+getstring, true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div><h2><?php echo $name; ?>'s Consult</h2></div>
        <div class="col1">
            <div>Consult Start Time:</div>
            <div>Consult End Time:</div>
            <div>No Show? :</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
            <div>
                <select name="start_hour">
                    <option></option>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                    <option>6</option>
                    <option>7</option>
                    <option>8</option>
                    <option>9</option>
                    <option>10</option>
                    <option>11</option>
                    <option>12</option>
                </select>
                :
                <select name="start_min">
                    <option></option>
                    <option>00</option>
                    <option>05</option>
                    <option>10</option>
                    <option>15</option>
                    <option>20</option>
                    <option>25</option>
                    <option>30</option>
                    <option>35</option>
                    <option>40</option>
                    <option>45</option>
                    <option>50</option>
                    <option>55</option>
                </select>
                -
                <select name="start_am">
                    <option></option>
                    <option>AM</option>
                    <option>PM</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <select name="end_hour">
                    <option></option>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                    <option>6</option>
                    <option>7</option>
                    <option>8</option>
                    <option>9</option>
                    <option>10</option>
                    <option>11</option>
                    <option>12</option>
                </select>
                :
                <select name="end_min">
                    <option></option>
                    <option>00</option>
                    <option>05</option>
                    <option>10</option>
                    <option>15</option>
                    <option>20</option>
                    <option>25</option>
                    <option>30</option>
                    <option>35</option>
                    <option>40</option>
                    <option>45</option>
                    <option>50</option>
                    <option>55</option>
                </select>
                -
                <select name="end_am">
                    <option></option>
                    <option>AM</option>
                    <option>PM</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div><input type="checkbox" name="no_show" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="notes">Notes:</div>
        <div class="notes"><textarea name="notes" rows="5" cols="53"></textarea></div>
        <div class="notes"><button type="button" onClick="saveClose();">Save & Close</button><span id="resultsContent" style="padding-left:1em"></span></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The AJAX call runs this PHP script:

```
<?php

$type   = $_GET['type'];
$id     = $_GET['id'];
$s_hour = $_GET['s_hour'];
$s_min  = $_GET['s_min'];
$s_am   = $_GET['s_am'];
$e_hour = $_GET['e_hour'];
$e_min  = $_GET['e_min'];
$e_am   = $_GET['e_am'];
$ns     = $_GET['ns'];
$ns     = (($ns == "true") ? "1" : "0");
$notes  = $_GET['notes'];


switch (true) {
    case empty($type):
        echo "\$type is broken!";
        break;
    case empty($s_hour):
        echo "\$s_hour is broken!";
        break;
    case empty($s_min):
        echo "\$s_min is broken!";
        break;
    case empty($s_am):
        echo "\$s_am is broken!";
        break;
    case empty($e_hour):
        echo "\$e_hour is broken!";
        break;
    case empty($e_min):
        echo "\$e_min is broken!";
        break;
    case empty($e_am):
        echo "\$e_am is broken!";
        break;
    case (!isset($ns)):
        echo "\$ns is broken!";
        break;
    case (!isset($notes)):
        echo "\$notes is broken!";
        break;

    default:
        // SALES APPTS.
        # ...
        # ...
        # ...

        // OTHER APPTS.
        # ...
        # ...
        # ...

        echo "Successful!";
        break;
}


?>
```

Like expected, Firefox and Chrome halt on every case statement until both the start time and end time are selected. Works perfectly.

IE, however, will halt on `case empty($s_hour):` every single time, no matter what. I can't even get past that first case statement to see if the rest are broken too. I do not understand.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as this application must be IE9 compatible.

Comment: Well it's unlikely to be a problem with your PHP code, because that will simply return a value.  Surely in IE it doesn't get stuck executing the PHP code.  If it does, it might be worth opening your PHP script in IE on it's own and seeing what data is returned, to see if it is acceptable.

Comment: Have you useed a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and see what is being sent up to the server that is "breaking" your php code?

Comment: @Coulton I think the point is that IE isn't sending the right data to the server for whatever reason

Comment: @epascarello I have never used Fiddler before. What is the difference between Fiddler2 and Fiddler4 (besides the required framework)?

Comment: you php-Code is wrapped in quotes here  `getstring += "?type=<?php echo $type ?>"; getstring += "&id=<?php echo $id ?>";`. Is this on purpose? Does it get escaped automatically?

Comment: @nozzleman What are you talking about? PHP strings don't get printed with quotes, so there's nothing to "escape"...unless you mean the strings themselves might have quotes inside of them? And that wouldn't make a discrepancy between IE and other browsers - it would fail in all

Comment: @jdstankosky for what you are doing it does not matter

Comment: thats what i was wondering too :) what i meant is i thought it should look sth. like this `getstring += "?type=" + <?php echo $type ?>;` or am i wrong?

Comment: @nozzleman - no, that's wrong. you're getting confused by the mixing of the languages. It might work if PHP's $type is numeric, but that would be by luck rather than design; really it is correct to have it inside the Javascript string.

Comment: it would be better to have the `saveClose()` function static (ie without any PHP code embedded in it), and have the relevant PHP values (type and id) passed into it as parameters.

Comment: have you tried doing `console.log(getstring)` to see what the code is actually posting? Use the browser debug tools to see the console output and compare the values between the two. This should show you what's different. (without even having to use Fiddler)

Comment: Also, do you actually need to support IE6 and 5.5? You could simplify things by throwing away that ActiveX bit.

Comment: Fiddler is showing that the `s_hour`, `s_min`, `s_am`, `e_hour`, `e_min`, and `e_am` variables are not getting passed in the get string; the variables are empty. However, `ns` and `notes` are being passed. This leads me to think that my method of getting the values from the drop select inputs is incorrect. Can anyone verify?

Comment: @SDC That makes a lot more sense than having to use Fiddler. Great suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to read the value of the value of the select boxes, but the 'value' property may not be populated as you expect, because it's trying to get the value property from the selected option, not the text of that option.

You should either add an explicit value attribute to the `<option>` elements like so:

```
<option value='12'>12</option>
```

or explicitly get the text of the selected option, like so:

```
var objStHr = document.getElementsByName('start_hour')[0];
var start_hour = objStHr.options[objStHr.value];
```

(I've used a temp var to hold the object for brevity since we have to reference it twice)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Adding the explicit value attribute, why the heck didn't I even already do this??? I can't believe I didn't notice. Anyways, it solved the problem elegantly, absolutely, and with the least amount of code changed. I like readability.

Answer (score 1):

If your values are coming from dropdowns, you shouldn't use `.value` on the `<select>` element  directly to access the selected option (the property is not updated on all browsers). Use this instead:

```
function getDropdownValue(el)
{
    return el.selectedIndex >= 0 ? el.options[el.selectedIndex].value : '';
}

start_hour = getDropdownValue(d.getElementsByName('start_hour')[0]);
// ...
```